# The page can't load page correctly in my flutter app (UPDATED) Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I have Updated the question that I posted :
I have page get widget from another dart file.
I changed all pages in one page using extract method instead of widget ,so i removed the future from the first function :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var username;
  var userId;
  var lang;
  var savedCourseId;
  var savedDayId;

// getting m_id from status user
  void getUserStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      username = preferences.getString('username');
      userId = preferences.getString('logined_id');
      lang = preferences.getString('lang');
    });
    var url =
        "http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/users/status_user.php?username=$username";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      savedCourseId = data['m_id'];
      savedDayId = int.parse(data['d_id']);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserStatus();

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: buildDrawerMyDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
        title: Text(
          'ژیان و قورئان',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('./assets/images/background.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )),
        child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  buildContainer(size, 1, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 2, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 3, userId, savedCourseId),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  buildContainer(size, 4, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 5, userId, savedCourseId),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  buildContainer(size, 6, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 7, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 8, userId, savedCourseId),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  buildContainer(size, 9, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 10, userId, savedCourseId),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  buildContainer(size, 11, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 12, userId, savedCourseId),
                  buildContainer(size, 13, userId, savedCourseId),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
//
  Container buildContainer(size, courseId, userID, savedCourseId) {
    return Container(
      width: 0.25 * size,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: courseId <= int.parse(savedCourseId)
            ? () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('weeks', arguments: {
                  'courseId': courseId,
                  'lang': lang,
                  'savedDayId': savedDayId,
                  'savedCourseID': int.parse(savedCourseId),
                  'userID': userID,
                });
              }
            : null,
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(courseId <= int.parse(savedCourseId)
              ? './assets/images/months/course' + courseId.toString() + '.png'
              : './assets/images/months/course' +
                  courseId.toString() +
                  'c.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now previous error is fixed but an error appear then the page loads successfully with this error on Debug Console :

```
Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null
```

How can I solve this now?

Comment: try to remove the app and run it again but firstly type ```flutter clean``` in the terminal and tell me what happend

Comment: it is same brother

Comment: I think as i tested it the app when load don't read the value of savedCourseId ,then when i save the page it read it

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Elmarakby I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many test i did i found the error is caused by savedCourseId variable ,at the page loading it has null data therefore it gave me this error ,thefore i add a condition statement if the value of savedCourseId is null just show conatiner else show the page detail ,thus no error found now :
the page is like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var username;
  var userId;
  var lang;
  var savedCourseId;
  var savedDayId;

// getting m_id from status user
  void getUserStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      username = preferences.getString('username');
      userId = preferences.getString('logined_id');
      lang = preferences.getString('lang');
    });
    var url =
        "http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/users/status_user.php?username=$username";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      savedCourseId = data['m_id'];
      savedDayId = int.parse(data['d_id']);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserStatus();

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: buildDrawerMyDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
        title: Text(
          'ژیان و قورئان',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('./assets/images/background.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )),
        child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: savedCourseId != null //---------Add this condition
            ? ListView(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      buildContainer(size, 1, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 2, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 3, userId, savedCourseId),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      buildContainer(size, 4, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 5, userId, savedCourseId),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      buildContainer(size, 6, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 7, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 8, userId, savedCourseId),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      buildContainer(size, 9, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 10, userId, savedCourseId),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      buildContainer(size, 11, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 12, userId, savedCourseId),
                      buildContainer(size, 13, userId, savedCourseId),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )
            : Container()),
      ),
    );
  }
//
  Container buildContainer(size, courseId, userID, savedCourseId) {
    return Container(
      width: 0.25 * size,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: courseId <= int.parse(savedCourseId)
            ? () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('weeks', arguments: {
                  'courseId': courseId,
                  'lang': lang,
                  'savedDayId': savedDayId,
                  'savedCourseID': int.parse(savedCourseId),
                  'userID': userID,
                });
              }
            : null,
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(courseId <= int.parse(savedCourseId)
              ? './assets/images/months/course' + courseId.toString() + '.png'
              : './assets/images/months/course' +
                  courseId.toString() +
                  'c.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these,

1. Run flutter clean
2. Use latest version "2.0.5" is in pubspec.yaml
3. Make sure the value you are setting doesn't have null. It is confusing at
   point, it will throw error on getInstance() while issue will be
   further setting null values. example below,

   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   prefs.setString('name', ((data != null) ? data : ""));